# How to prepare a custom keypoints dataset for WongKinYiu/Yolov7 Pose Estimation?

Tags: pytorch, yolo, pose-estimation, keypoint

How do I prepare a custom keypoints dataset for [WongKinYiu/yolov7](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7#pose-estimation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keypoints format is described here

https://cocodataset.org/#format-data

In particular this line

```
annotation{
    "keypoints" : [x1,y1,v1,...],
    ...
}
```

says that keypoints are an array `x1,y1,v1,...`.

The official yolov7-pose github
https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/tree/pose
has link to download prepared COCO dataset
[[Keypoints Labels of MS COCO 2017]](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/releases/download/v0.1/coco2017labels-keypoints.zip)
Download it, open and go to directory `labels\train2017`. You can open any of the `txt` files and you will see lines looking something like this

```
0 0.671279 0.617945 0.645759 0.726859 0.519751 0.381250 2.000000 0.550936 0.348438 2.000000 0.488565 0.367188 2.000000 0.642412 0.354687 2.000000 0.488565 0.395313 2.000000 0.738046 0.526563 2.000000 0.446985 0.534375 2.000000 0.846154 0.771875 2.000000 0.442827 0.812500 2.000000 0.925156 0.964063 2.000000 0.507277 0.698438 2.000000 0.702703 0.942187 2.000000 0.555094 0.950000 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

This line has the following format

```
class top_left_x top_left_y bottom_right_x bottom_right_y kpt1_x kpt1_y kpt1_v kpt2_x kpt2_y kpt2_v ...
```

This is the code (from `general.py`) responsible for loading it

```
def xywhn2xyxy(x, w=640, h=640, padw=0, padh=0, kpt_label=False):
    # Convert nx4 boxes from [x, y, w, h] normalized to [x1, y1, x2, y2] where xy1=top-left, xy2=bottom-right
    # it does the same operation as above for the key-points
    y = x.clone() if isinstance(x, torch.Tensor) else np.copy(x)
    y[:, 0] = w * (x[:, 0] - x[:, 2] / 2) + padw  # top left x
    y[:, 1] = h * (x[:, 1] - x[:, 3] / 2) + padh  # top left y
    y[:, 2] = w * (x[:, 0] + x[:, 2] / 2) + padw  # bottom right x
    y[:, 3] = h * (x[:, 1] + x[:, 3] / 2) + padh  # bottom right y
    if kpt_label:
        num_kpts = (x.shape[1]-4)//2
        for kpt in range(num_kpts):
            for kpt_instance in range(y.shape[0]):
                if y[kpt_instance, 2 * kpt + 4]!=0:
                    y[kpt_instance, 2*kpt+4] = w * y[kpt_instance, 2*kpt+4] + padw
                if y[kpt_instance, 2 * kpt + 1 + 4] !=0:
                    y[kpt_instance, 2*kpt+1+4] = h * y[kpt_instance, 2*kpt+1+4] + padh
    return y
```

which is called from

```
labels[:, 1:] = xywhn2xyxy(labels[:, 1:], ratio[0] * w, ratio[1] * h, padw=pad[0], padh=pad[1], kpt_label=self.kpt_label)
```

Note the `1` offset in `labels[:, 1:]`, which omits the class label.
The label coordinates must be normalized as stated here

```
assert (l[:, 5::3] <= 1).all(), 'non-normalized or out of bounds coordinate labels'
assert (l[:, 6::3] <= 1).all(), 'non-normalized or out of bounds coordinate labels'
```

Getting the format of labels right is the only tricky part. The rest is to have images stored in the right directory. The structure is

```
images/
    train/
        file_name1.jpg
        ...
    test/
    val/
labels/
    train/
        file_name1.txt
        ...
    test/
    val/
train.txt
test.txt
val.txt
```

where `train.txt` contains paths to images. It's contents look like this

```
./images/train/file_name1.jpg
...
```